# Where is the "group-separator" option listed in the grep documentation?

Tags: grep, man, documentation

My flavor of grep supports `--group-separator` and `--no-group-separator` but I only discovered this by googling how to solve a problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168065/how-do-i-get-rid-of-line-separator-when-using-grep-with-context-lines

I tried:

```
grep --help | grep separator
```

and

```
man grep
/group-separator
```

with no results.

Where would I have found this information without Google and Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation of most GNU utilities is primarily written in `texinfo` format, from which are derived the `info` pages, HTML documentation and formats for printing like PDF or postscript.

For interactive browsing, that's generally the `info` format you want. texinfo documentations borrows the table-of-content and index concepts from books. In `info`, the native GNU utility to browse `info` documentation, you can query the table of contents (the various nodes of the documentation) with <kbd>g</kbd>, and the index with <kbd>i</kbd>. Completion is available for both.

So here, I'd do:

```
info grep
```

And within `info`, press `i` to bring up the index prompt, type `group` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see the possible completions. That brings `group separator` straight away. If it hadn't, if there had been no index entry for it for instance, you could have search the entire text with <kbd>s</kbd>.

You can also invoke `info` as:

```
info  --index-search=group-separator grep
```

Or press <kbd>I</kbd> instead of <kbd>i</kbd> to get a virtual text node with the list of index entries that match your query.